# How to concatenate if statement inside echo in php?

Tags: php, if-statement, string-concatenation

Is it possible to concatenate an if statement inside echo in php? How can I attach some condition based html to an html inside an echo? Something like as follow:

```
<?php
echo '<div class="main">Some html</div>' . if (is_page('my-account')) {
echo '<div class="account_data">Some account related data</div>';
}; . ;
?>
```

Comment: No. You can use a ternary, but otherwise you'll have to end the statement before you go into the if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will help to you. Try this.

```
<?php
$html = '';
$html .= '<div class="main">Some html</div>';
 if (is_page('my-account')) {
    $html .= '<div class="account_data">Some account related data</div>';
 }
echo $html;
```

Comment: This is adding the html inside the if statement to the top of the rest of html. I need it to be at the bottom of everything.

Comment: @teccraft what do you mean ??

Comment: I mean that due to this code, `'<div class="account_data">Some account related data</div>'` appears on top of `'<div class="main">Some html</div>'`. I am already getting this result in my existing approach which is not required.

Comment: describe your expected output. @teccraft

Comment: I have some existing html like `<div class="main">Some html</div>` inside echo. And I want to concatenate `<div class="account_data">Some account related data</div>` with it. But as a result, the html which I am concatenating at the end appears on the top of the html to which I am concatenating this.

Comment: I have resolved my issue. Actually, your solution was working fine. I was outputing `<h2></h2>` instead of `<div></div>` which was the main cause of appearing on top of the other html.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a `ternary operator` like so

```
<?php

    printf(
        '<div class="main">Some html</div>%s',
        is_page('my-account') ? '<div class="account_data">Some account related data</div>' : ''
    );

?>
```